# ROS Answers SE migration: Edit a rosbag

Tags: ros, rosbag, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am interested in interactively editing a bag. Specifically, I have some bags which consist mainly of image data, and I want to delete some frames for various uninteresting reasons.

I don't fathom it would be crazy difficult to roll my own program which opens a bag, reads and displays each frame using OpenCV and ask the user to write that frame to a new bag (non-image data is always kept). Has anybody done anything like this before?

Alternatively, could I use the rxbag plugin API to delete messages directly from within rxbag (eg, selecting them in the timeline and deleting)?

I have very little experience with bags besides record/play and a quick glance at the API seems to suggest that editing isn't on the menu. If anybody has done any editing of rosbags, I would certainly appreciate any help you could give me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34740/edit-a-rosbag/) by [NStiurca](https://answers.ros.org/users/393/nstiurca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the [rosbag API](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Code%20API) and the [rosbag cookbook](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Cookbook). The cookbook has some samples of ways to modify a bag file.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think you can edit a bag easily. What you can do is re-export some parts into a new bag. As far as I know, rxbag has support for doing that, but a simple python program that does exactly the same using the rosbag API shouldn't be hard either.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1